# Cant figure out search error

Tags: javascript

working on this, too. I've fixed the spelling and (i think) the bracket errors. Also fixed a couple errors I saw that stood out, but didn't get too far. I'm still stumped as to where to go with it next.

```
(function(){

// Variable initialization (DO NOT FIX ANY OF THE BELOW VAR's)
var resultsDIV = document.getElementById("results"),
    searchInput = document.forms[0].search,
    currentSearch = ''
    ;

// Validates search query
var validate = function(query){

    // Trim whitespace from start and end of search query
    while (query.charAt[0] === " "){
        query = query.substring(1, query.length);
    };
    while (query.charAt(query.length-1) === ""){
        query = query.substring(0, query.length - 1);
    };

        // Check search length, must have 3 characters
        if (query.length < 3){
            alert ("Your search query is too small, try again.");

            // (DO NOT FIX THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW)
            searchInput.focus();
            return;
        };

        search (query);
    };

    // Finds search matches
    var search = function (query){

    // split the user's search query string into an array
    var queryArray = query.join(" ");

    // array to store matched results from database.js
    var results = [];

    // loop through each index of db array
    for(var i=0, j=db.length; i<j; i++){

        // each db[i] is a single video item, each title ends with a pipe "|"
        // save a lowercase variable of the video title
        var dbTitleEnd = db[i].indexOf('|');
        var dbitem = db[i].tolowercase().substring(0, dbTitleEnd);

        // loop through the user's search query words
        // save a lowercase variable of the search keyword
        for(var ii=0, jj=queryArray.length; ii<jj; ii++){
            var qitem = queryArray[ii].tolowercase();

            // is the keyword anywhere in the video title?
            // If a match is found, push full db[i] into results array
            var compare = dbitem.indexOf(qitem);
            if(compare !== -1){
                results.push(db[i]);
            };
        };
    };

    };

        results.sort();

            // Check that matches were found, and run output functions
            if(results.length = );{
                noMatch();
            }else{
                showMatches(results);
            };


        // Put "No Results" message into page (DO NOT FIX THE HTML VAR NOR THE innerHTML)
        var noMatch = function(){
            var html = ''+
                    '<p>No Results found.</p>'+
                    '<p style="font-size:10px;">Try searching for "JavaScript".  Just an idea.</p>'
                ;
            resultsDIV.innerHTML = html;
        };

        // Put matches into page as paragraphs with anchors
        var showMatches = function(results){

            // THE NEXT 4 LINES ARE CORRECT.
            var html = '<p>Results</p>',
                title,
                url
                ;

            // loop through all the results search() function
            for(var i=0, j=results.length; i<j; i++){

                // title of video ends with pipe
                // pull the title's string using index numbers
                titleEnd = results[i].indexOf('|');
                title = results[i].subString(0, titleEnd);

                // pull the video url after the title
                url = results[i].substring(results[i].indexOf('|')+1, results[i].length);

                // make the video link - THE NEXT LINE IS CORRECT.
                html += '<p><a href=' + url + '>' + title + '</a></p>';
            };
            resultsDIV.innerHTML = html; //THIS LINE IS CORRECT.
        };

        // The onsubmit event will be reviewed in upcoming Course Material.
        // THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW IS CORRECT
        document.forms[0].onsubmit = function(){
            var query = searchInput.value;
            validqte(query);

            // return false is needed for most events - this will be reviewed in upcoming course material
            // THE LINE DIRECTLY BELOW IS CORRECT
            return false;
            ;

        })();
```

Comment: You forgot $ mark at the beginning

Comment: You have typos and missing curly braces everywhere.  validqte(query);

Comment: You can check your typo error on web console. Try using it :D

Comment: I am using web console and jshint.com but nothing will fix this and i already caught the typo but it still wont work and I try and place curly braces in certain spots I think need them still nothing fixes my issue

Comment: @edisonthk - `$` isn't needed, the outermost function isn't supposed to be a call to jQuery, it's just to create private scope. Joshua - If you've fixed typos and curly brace problems please click "edit" and add the fixed version to your question so that these errors don't distract us from whatever the real problem is.

Comment: Ok updated with what I fixed

Answer (score 0):

There are a few syntax errors which should prevent this from running at all.

```
// syntax error
var results = ();

// should be
var results = [];
```

Also it appears that the definition of `showMatches` ends with an unmatched right parenthesis.

Given that somehow the code is running with these syntax errors (and possibly others I didn't notice), the (a) glaring issue is:

```
if (results.length = 0) {
```

Yeah, that's an assignment, not a comparison.  You just set the array's length to zero, which effectively clears it.  This both fails the length test here (returning 0), then hands the now empty array off to be displayed as results, but of course it's now an array of length 0.

On another note, probably not an actual problem but I can't help it.  The `while` loop business to trim the string?  Yeah, don't do that.  Use `trim`.  If you need a polyfill there's always:

```
if (!String.prototype.trim) {
  String.prototype.trim = function () {
    return this.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '');
  };
}
```